# Python Deep compare data types of values two dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, types

Consider two python dictionaries:

```
>>> a = {'one': 10, 'two': 10.1, 'three': {'x': '10'}}
>>> b = {'one': 20, 'two': 20.1, 'three': {'x': '20'}}
```

Obviously a comparison of the two dictionaries `a == b` will evaluate to `False`, however, the data types of the values are all equal.

What is the simplest way to compare the datatypes of the values of the two dictionaries? Is there an existing python library to do the same.

**Corner cases**:

- The solution would have to recursively compare in case values are themselves dictionaries
- Only exact equivalence of types are required (int != float)

Comment: See my edited answer for a cleaner solution :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the [`deepdiff`](https://github.com/seperman/deepdiff) module.

Install with: `pip install deepdiff`

Example usage:

```
from deepdiff import DeepDiff

a = {'one': 10, 'three': {'x': '10'}, 'two': '10.1'}
b = {'one': 10, 'three': {'x': '10'}, 'two': '10.1'}

i = {'one': 10, 'two': '10.1', 'three': {'x': '10'}}
j = {'one': 20, 'two': '20.1', 'three': {'x': '20'}}

m = {'one': 10, 'three': {'x': 10}, 'two': '10.1'}
n = {'one': 20, 'two': '20.1', 'three': {'x': '20'}}

ddiff1 = DeepDiff(a, b, ignore_order=True)
ddiff2 = DeepDiff(i, j, ignore_order=True)
ddiff3 = DeepDiff(m, n, ignore_order=True)

print(f"{ddiff1}\n{'type_changes' in ddiff1}\n")
print(f"{ddiff2}\n{'type_changes' in ddiff2}\n")
print(f"{ddiff3}\n{'type_changes' in ddiff3}\n")
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> {}
> False
>
> {'values_changed': {"root['two']": {'new_value': '20.1', 'old_value': '10.1'}, "root['three']['x']": {'new_value': '20', 'old_value': '10'}, "root['one']": {'new_value': 20, 'old_value': 10}}}
> False
>
> {'type_changes': {"root['three']['x']": {'old_type': <class 'int'>, 'new_type': <class 'str'>, 'old_value': 10, 'new_value': '20'}}, 'values_changed': {"root['one']": {'new_value': 20, 'old_value': 10}, "root['two']": {'new_value': '20.1', 'old_value': '10.1'}}}
> True
> ```

---

**Original answer that only uses the standard library:**

Here's a relatively simple solution which can handle the items being in a different order and will correctly return `False` if there are a different amount of keys. This will also handle nested dictionaries:

```
def same_types(a, b):
    if len(a) != len(b):
        return False
    for key, value in a.items():
        if key not in b or type(value) != type(b[key]):
            return False
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            return same_types(value, b[key])
    return True
```